# How do you mutablely share a single struct instance to multiple consumers (like a service)?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Imagine you have an HTTP API as an interface for a counter. The counter state lives in an object called `CounterService` and you can `increment()` the counter state.

A simple TypeScript example would look like:

```js
class CounterService {
   public value: number = 0

   public increment(): void {
      this.value = this.value + 1
   }

   public decrement(): void {
      this.value = this.value - 1
   }
}

void function main() {
   const api = express()
   const counterService = new CounterService()

   api.get('/value', getValueHandler(counterService))
   api.post('/increment', incrementHandler(counterService))
   api.post('/decrement', decrementHandler(counterService))

   api.listen(3000)
}()

function getValueHandler(counterService: CounterService): express.Handler {
   return function(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
      res.send(counterService.value)
   }
}

function incrementHandler(counterService: CounterService): express.Handler  {
   return function(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
      counterService.increment()
      res.sendStatus(204)
   }
}

// ...
```

In the above code I am sharing the `counterService` object to three functions. One requires read only access but the other two are both required to mutate it.

Now I understand this is not thread safe as the state should be locked behind a mutex, so I assume that's part of the puzzle. Broadly though, how would someone achieve something similar to this in rust?

```rust
struct CounterService {
   value: i32
}

impl CounterService {
  fn increment(&mut self) {
    self.value = self.value + 1
  }

  fn decrement(&mut self) {
    self.value = self.value - 1
  }
}

fn main {
//not sure how to make the equiv http server indicating callbacks, yet
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you answered it yourself - wrap it in a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html). It will give a mutable access to the one holding the lock.

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let svc = CounterService { value: 0 };
    let data = Mutex::new(svc);

    // .lock() does NOT require mut!
    // Yet it gives you mutable access
    let mut guard = data.lock().unwrap();
    guard.increment();

    drop(guard); // unlock the lock, so we can print the non-mut variable
    println!("{:?}", data);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct CounterService {
    value: i32,
}

impl CounterService {
    fn increment(&mut self) {
        self.value = self.value + 1
    }

    fn decrement(&mut self) {
        self.value = self.value - 1
    }
}
```

And if you want to share it to multiple handlers, just wrap the `Mutex` in an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) which is a thread-safe reference-counting smart pointer:

```rust
fn main() {
    let svc = CounterService { value: 0 };
    let shared = Arc::new(Mutex::new(svc));

    handler_a(shared.clone());
    handler_b(shared.clone());
    handler_c(shared.clone());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is very helpful. When considering performance, this would effectively block access to the whole service for all operations (read, write and non conflicting writes). Is it possible to wrap the internal "CounterService.value" property in the mutex and hand out read only access to the service? Methods like increment and decrement would buffer behind the mutex where accessing the value would be immediate.

Comment: There is a `RwLock` that allows multiple read-only consumers, but if you are having a stateless service (à la Spring) , then just create a new instance per handler - no need for locks, shared pointers, complexity,etc.

Comment: In the case where the application is stateless (say all handlers call out to an external API, a database or something), to prevent blocking incoming requests until the requests resolve - would you need to implement a queue, dedicate a thread to maintaining the queue? Is that what something like Tokio is for?

Comment: There are two approaches to that problem - one is "thread per request" - i.e. you spawn a new thread for each request or use a thread pool to manage the threads.  The other is to use non-blocking APIs where you can schedule concurrently (but not in parallel!) many tasks on a single thread. The second approach scales better as the number of concurrent tasks increases, but is much more complex to implement. Async/await is one of the ways to tackle that complexity and Tokio is just one impl of an async task scheduler.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my questions. I know the original question was vague but your insight really helped me understand some of the nuances of parallelism + concurrency. Learning Rust has also been fantastic in highlighting how many data races I have written in my Go applications :laugh: